# Replacing backslash with two backlashes in ansible

Tags: ansible

How do I replace a backslash with 2 backslashes in ansible?

I tried the following code:

```yaml
---
- name: Test
  hosts: 127.0.0.1

  tasks:
    - name: Set variable
      set_fact:
        admin : 'auth\peppa'

    - name: debug1
      debug:
        msg: "Value of admin = {{ admin }}"


    - name: Replace backslash with two backslashes
      set_fact:
        admin2 : '{{ admin|replace("\\","\\\\") }}'

    - name: debug2
      debug:
        msg: "Value of admin2 = {{ admin2 }}"
```

I am getting the following output:

```
TASK [Set variable] **************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [debug1] ********************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "Value of admin = auth\\peppa"
}

TASK [Replace backslash with two backslashes] ************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [debug2] ********************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "Value of admin2 = auth\\peppa"
}
```

The output is not what I am expecting

1. The value of `admin` and `admin2` are the same based on the `debug` statement
2. Also why the output of task `debug` is `auth\\peppa` instead of `auth\peppa`

The output I am expecting is

```
TASK [debug1] ********************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "Value of admin = auth\peppa"
}

TASK [Replace backslash with two backslashes] ************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [debug2] ********************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "Value of admin2 = auth\\peppa"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [single-quoted style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#732-single-quoted-style) and put the parameters into the variables. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ admin | replace(match, replace) }}"
      vars:
        admin: 'auth\peppa'
        match: '\'
        replace: '\\'
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: auth\\peppa
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I'm curious why it doesn't work work when I use a string literal?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your result `"Value of admin = auth\\peppa"`. Try to double-check your code step by step.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with ansible and jinja2 version?  osboxes@osboxes:~/ansible$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.14.5]
  config file = None
  python version = 3.10.10 (main, May  8 2023, 08:23:45) [GCC 6.3.0 20170516] (/usr/local/bin/python3.10)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True

Comment: FYI, my versions: 2.16.4 / 3.11.6 / 3.1.3